# Fast columns sorting of matrix refering another vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to sort the columns of a matrix based on the another vector values in a
fast way in matlab.
Let assume  I have a reference vector:

```
a = [1 8 3];
```

And the matrix I wanna sort by rows

```
b =[2 3 4
    5 6 4
    1 2 1];
```

And I want the result based on the vector `a` if the sorted a is

```
 a = [8 3 1]
```

the sorted matrix will be now

```
b = [3 4 2 
     6 4 5
     2 1 1];
```

So the index of the first vector is the same with the index of the columns 
So we sort columns based on the values of the vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Matlab the [`sort` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) returns two variables, the first is the sorted vector/matrix and the second is a set of indices that can be combined with the original data to produce the sorted values.

```
A = [ 5 4 1 2 3 ];

[A_sorted1, idx] = sort(A);

A_sorted2 = A(idx);
```

`A_sorted1` and `A_sorted2` are equivalent.

If the number of rows in `b` is equal to the number of elements in `a` then you can simply use:

```
[~, idx] = sort(a);
b_sorted = b(idx,:);
```

And if you want to sort by columns use:

```
b_sorted = b(:,idx);
```